# find min cost in selecting values

Tags: java

I have come across this question and not able to find optimal solution.
given 3 lists and 1 number, cost - [2,3,1,6,4] - cost of picking the particular element compatible1 -[1,1,0,1,0]  compatible2 - [0,1,0,0,1]
min compatible - 2

so here, we have to pick values from cost such that there are min 2 (given number) that are tagged as 1 in compatible 1 and compatible 2. The question is to find min total cost of picking those indexes.

we have to pick index 0, 1, 5 to get least total cost. ( index 0 and 1 for compatible 1, and 1, 5 for compatible 2) totalling to cost of 9.

i tried to sort cost and fetch common first and then different ones but its not ideal.

Comment: Pls post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of what you’ve tried.

Answer (score 0):

Consider utilizing [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) to implement an approach to solve your [Knapsack Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem):

```
from itertools import combinations
from typing import Optional


def get_min_cost(cost: list[int], compatible1: list[int], compatible2: list[int],
                 min_compatible: int) -> Optional[int]:
  n = len(cost)
  min_cost = None
  for num_items in range(min_compatible, n + 1):
    for indices in combinations(range(n), num_items):
      c1_count = sum(compatible1[i] for i in indices)
      c2_count = sum(compatible2[i] for i in indices)
      total_cost = sum(cost[i] for i in indices)
      if c1_count >= min_compatible and c2_count >= min_compatible:
        min_cost = min(min_cost,
                       total_cost) if min_cost is not None else total_cost
  return min_cost


result = get_min_cost(cost=[2, 3, 1, 6, 4],
                      compatible1=[1, 1, 0, 1, 0],
                      compatible2=[0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
                      min_compatible=2)
print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
9
```